Figuring out Rivnut size to use
I need to install rivnuts in a 1/4" aluminum plate.
I bought a Wetol rivnut tool from Amazon which came with a bunch of nuts and I'm trying to figure out which size to use.
The sizing instruction seems a bit confusing (image attached)
There are 2 grip ranges mentioned for each nut size. How do I figure out which size to use for the 1/4" plate and the relevant hole size to drill ?
Thanks


This question seems more about how to use a device and work on a craft than how to fix something in one's home. Device usage and crafting are off topic on DIY.SE.

The "two grip ranges" are associated with two different lengths in the right-most column.
The only sizes that offer a "grip range" including 1/4" (6.35 mm) is the 24mm M10s with 13.5 mm A dimension (13mm hole) and the 25mm M12 with 14mm A dimension (15mm hole.)
